# Could not convert socket to TLS;

Tags: java, javamail

me sale este error en Java, a alguien más le ha pasado esto ¿?

Mi configuración es la siguiente:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(direccionCorreo, password);
            }
        });

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(direccionCorreo, "SIS"));
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));
message.setSubject("Cita agendada");
message.setContent(body, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
Transport.send(message);
```

El error en consola es el siguiente:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;

nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher
suites are inappropriate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te funciona esa configuración usa esta bro

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Sobres :D

Comment: Sólo para añadir: específicar el protocolo en detalle evita que el protocolo por defecto en un servidor mal configurado arruine todo. Es posible toparse con clientes o servidores que usen protocolos deprecados por defecto, así que decirles que usen el que sabemos que funciona, va a destrabar la cosa.

Answer (score 0):

En el objeto props, debes agregar el siguiente atributo:

```
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Ello soluciono un problema similar que tenia al tuyo.